# Is there any way I can bypass symlinks from php open_basedir?

Tags: php, apache, open-basedir

I have configured `open_basedir` in Apache virtual host in Linux which is working fine.

```
<Directory /var/www/abc/public_html>
     php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/abc/public_html"
</Directory>
```

I am required to allow a single symlink which is located outside the specified basedir (`/var/www/abc/public_html/files --> ../files`).

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: The whole point if that configuration option is to securely prevent any access outside that folder.

Comment: Yes. But I am searching for an exception for a single symlink. Somehow I add the path somewhere to allow the specific link.

Comment: Sorry, but what sense is there in a general protection mechanism if it allows "exceptions"? Think a bit about what you ask for...

Comment: Thanks for the response. Found my answer. That was actually pretty simple.

Comment: Great to hear! Please share your answer for others then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to bypass the `open_basedir` restriction, no. However, you *could* just include the additional symlink path to your `open_basedir` since it can accept more than just one path.

`open_basedir=/var/www/abc/public_html:/var/www/abc/files`

> All symbolic links are resolved, so it's not possible to avoid this restriction with a symlink.
>
> [PHP Manual: `open_basedir`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)

What you have to keep in mind is that `open_basedir` allows everything in a given path. So that means once access is granted to the path `/var/www/abc/files`, everything in that path like `/var/www/abc/files/foo`, `/var/www/abc/files/bar`, etc... is also allowed.